# How to pass variable from batch file into task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey, windows-task-scheduler

I have verified that my variable is in my batch file via -

```
echo %1
```

So this is the next command in my batch file -

```
schtasks /run /TN 7fd19ac6-6e5f-4bf9-8313-2ed6ee474fa0
```

Which has been setup previously. In this setup I have set the Program to run as -

```
dec.ahk
```

and the argument as

```
%1
```

This is obviously running an autohotkey script and I'm trying to pass that %1 from my batch file. When I run the above I have a message box in autohotkey telling me the value of %1, and in this case it returns "%1", not the file name I initially clicked on and want to pass. So how to get the value of this filename into schtasks argument properly?

Adding to the schtasks command line like this does not work -

```
schtasks /run /TN 7fd19ac6-6e5f-4bf9-8313-2ed6ee474fa0 %1
```

Answer (score 0):

the filename can have no spaces in it.
change the scheduled task argument to %zdec%

```
setx zdec %1
schtasks /run /TN 7fd19ac6-6e5f-4bf9-8313-2ed6ee474fa0
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v zdec /f
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Am I doing this the logical way? If I could not use a batch file that would be better. I just want to run the autohotkey script on Win7 without that UAC popup showing and using task scheduler does work good but if there is an easier method I'm all ears.

Comment: why haven't you turned uac off?

Comment: do a google search for `running ahk with standard privileges`

Comment: if I had known you were doing this to get around uac I would have answered in a different way. Your approach is like killing a fly w/ an atom bomb.  Turn uac off,  Write your scripts to need only standard privileges, Use runas, ….  That said my answer does work.